# Glympse API while sending sms TICKET_INVITE_FAILED

Tags: android, glympse

Hi I using Commercial SDK and I have problem with send sms. When i tried to send by email it works, but when I try to send via sms i get following events: TICKET_CREATED,TICKET_TRACK_CHANGED, TICKET_INVITE_FAILED (handled by listener). My code:

Calling createGlympse method:

```
Wrapper().createGlympse(3600000, "xxx-xxx-xxx", "Going home!");
```

"xxx-xxx-xxx" - phone number

In my wrapper:

```
createGlympse(..){
..
    GInvite recipient = GlympseFactory.createInvite(GC.INVITE_TYPE_SMS,null, address);
..
}
```

What I do worng or what is phone number patter? I tried on device which avaible send sms manualy and via glympse server.
Maybe is the sandbox restriction?

Comment: "using Commercial SDK" what about using their support?

Comment: I haven't access to account.